# Use @ionic/core without unpkg cdn in non-Ionic (Angular 6) app

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am attempting to use components in the `@ionic/core` package in an Angular 6 app. (it's not a CLI app, and I cannot use `@ionic/angular`).

I cannot get the components to work without importing directly from the cdn, i.e.

```
<link href="https://unpkg.com/@ionic/core@4.0.0-beta.13/css/ionic.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://unpkg.com/@ionic/core@4.0.0-beta.13/dist/ionic.js"></script>
```

I've added `@ionic/core` as an npm dependency, and tried to import it every which way, but can't get the components to render.

Here is a Stackblitz editor: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-34cilj

The `ion-list`'s in the `app.component.html` should work [per the docs](https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/api/list) when imported correctly. There are some commented import attempts in the `app.module.ts`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the illumination, that's exactly what I wanted. This is what I did to make it work:

- Solution 1: as it worked for me by importing these libraries in index.html file of your Stackblitz project (I saved the file in Stackblitz so you can check), I did the same in my angular src/index.html file and also worked. The problem is I don't want to have the project with external CDN dependences, so I created the second solution.
- Solution 2: use it locally:

  1. Install ionic core with:

     ```
     npm install @ionic/core --save
     ```
  2. Add these lines to vendor.ts file (I have this file imported from main.ts for the sake of cleanliness, but it's also valid if these lines are imported directly in main.ts):

     ```
     import "../node_modules/@ionic/core/css/ionic.bundle.css";
     import "../node_modules/@ionic/core/dist/ionic.js";
     ```

     or, if you have these files located in another path, e.g. in /src/

     ```
     import "./ionic.bundle.css";
     import "./ionic.js";
     ```
  3. Copy the folder node_modules/@ionic/core/dist/ionic in /src, at the same level of "assets"
  4. Tell Angular Cli to consider this folder as an exportable folder when serve and/or building, by adding this line to the angular-cli.json file:

     ```
     "assets": [ 
         "ionic",
         ...
     ],
     ```

I'm thinking in create a new script in package.json for copying the "ionic" folder to /src once the package @ionic/core is upgraded by npm, but I don't think it is neccesary and I always remove the ~ char to every package to be sure npm can't breakg my project.

I hope it helps!

Comment: I couldnt manage to get this to work - when i add the assets, i start getting all sorts of typescript errors - ERROR in src/ionic/swiper/swiper-interface.d.ts(1,58): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'swiper/dist/js/swiper.esm'.